# Can't ssh into linux container on Azure App Service - "SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: azure, docker, ssh, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to ssh into a container for Azure app service. I have followed the instructions for configuring my container here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/containers/configure-custom-container#enable-ssh

and the instructions to connect here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ssh-support

Here are the relevant steps in my docker file:

```
RUN apt-get update \ 
     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dialog \
     && apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server \
     && echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd 

EXPOSE 8000 2222

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

CMD ./bin/start.sh
```

where start.sh starts runs service ssh start. The sshd_config file is

```
# This is ssh server systemwide configuration file.
#
# /etc/sshd_config

Port            2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

When I try and connect by ssh from the portal it first says `"CONNECTED | CREDENTIALS"` then after 30 seconds or so it says `"SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <ip>:2222"`

Not sure why this is not connecting?

Answer (score 3):

What fixed my error was to specified missing runtime directory that sshd requires. For debian Linux distor it I had to create `/run/sshd` directory. Another thing that was important is to start `sshd` daemon by full for me it was `/usr/sbin/sshd`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
RUN mkdir /run/sshd

WORKDIR /app
COPY startup.sh /app
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

EXPOSE 80 2222

CMD /app/startup.sh
```

**/app/startup.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Start sshd"
/usr/sbin/sshd

echo "Start nginx"
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

**sshd_config**

```
Port                2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin         yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

To verify that you can ssh into container run this command

```sh
# Password: Docker!
$ ssh root@IP_OF_CONTAINER -p 2222

# Debug
ssh root@172.17.0.26 -p 2222 -vvvv
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok just got this to work it seemed putting #!/bin/bash was left out the top of start.sh

Comment: It's not related at all.

Comment: You can change line CMD /app/startup.sh by CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"] and delete /app/startup.sh it's not necesary.